# Check variable number of conditions within list comprehension

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

suppose check(x) is a function which returns true/false.
suppose foo is a list of tuples

I want to filter the tuples in foo. But the number of conditions, n, I want to check will vary

n=2

```
[ x for x in foo if ( check(x[0]) and check(x[1]) ) ]
```

n=3

```
[ x for x in foo if ( check(x[0]) and check(x[1]) and check(x[2]) ) ]
```

any way to write this list comprehension as a function of n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason not to use the built-in `all(…)`?

> #### all(...)
>
> ```
> all(iterable) -> bool
> ```
>
> Return `True` if `bool(x)` is `True` for all values `x` in the `iterable`.
>
> If the `iterable` is empty, return `True`.

If `n` is length of your `x`s, then you can use:

```
[ x for x in foo if all(check(y) for y in x) ]
```

If `n >= len(x)`:

```
[ x for x in foo if all(check(x[i]) for i in range(n)) ]
```

If `n` might be bigger than `len(x)`, then limit the range to `min(n, len(x))`.

Comment: Lol! At the same time!

Comment: This would be better if you explained to the OP how to incorporate `n` into the genexp.

Comment: @DSM, ah, I just assumed that `n == len(x)`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Kay : what if I dont want to check over every index, but only up to some other variable n

Comment: FWIW I was thinking `(check(y) for y in x[:n])`.  Now this does materialize an iterable whereas the `range` doesn't, but in practice it's not likely to be a problem.

Comment: @DSM, depending on the nature of `x`, even the clumsy looking `all(imap(lambda y, _: check(y), x, range(n)))` might be the best solution.

Comment: If we're itertools-ing it up, I'd probably use `islice` before `imap` and go `(check(y) for y in islice(x, n))` mostly 'cause it's easier to read.

Comment: @DSM, yes, much easier on the eyes!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

```
[ x for x in foo if all(check(x[i]) for i in range(n)) ]
```

Where `n` is the number of checks

You can also do it with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
[ x for x in foo if len(filter(check, x[:n])) == n ]
```